# Store 600 KB of session data per registered user in Heroku

Tags: heroku

For a given application, we would need to store about 600 Kb of data in the web session per registered user who connects on our website. We would have about 1,000 registered users in parallel hence we need to store 600 Mb of session data.

The reason we need so much data in the session is to avoid querying frequently a table with about 1 billion rows in the database.

I understood Heroku stores session information in the database. This is fine as it means the session data is available cross-dynos (no session affinity).

Is there another way of storing more efficiently information across dynos ? Reading the docs, I found memcachier.

My questions would be the following :

- Do you think storing that amount of session in the database would be performant enough
- Do you suggest other caching systems than memcachier to store session information available across different dynos ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Olivier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku does not store session information at all -- how session information is stored depends entirely on your application and your application's framework and that will work in the same way regardless of whether you are deployed on Heroku or any other system.

As far as what kind of storage is sensible, however: it sounds like cookie storage is right out, due to the volume of data.  Database storage was the de facto default for web applications for a long time and there's nothing wrong with it.  Memcached would be faster, and how much faster exactly depends on your configuration (are you using connection pooling? does each page view hit the database for something else anyways? what is your caching system like?).  But as long as you're sure this strategy of storing so much info in session data is sound, then the difference between database and memcached storage will not be great.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your help ! Regarding volume of data in the session, I have investigated different strategies and tried to optimise the SQL queries but given the 1 billion rows table, I think it is the most efficient. The application will be written using Django / PostreSQL.